# Arresting Flask Mail delivery failure

Tags: python, flask

I have the following code that I believed would help me check if email is provided is valid and would be accepted for delivery:

```
@app.route("/email_send/<email>")
 def email_send(email=None):
 return_message=None
 msg = Message('Online Enquiry', sender='sender@gmail.com', recipients=[email])
 msg.body ='We have received your message. We shall be communicating with you'
 try:
    mail.send(msg)
    return_message='SUCCESS'
 except Exception as e:
    return_message='FAILED'
 return json.dumps(str(return_message))
```

The problem is that it is always returning 'SUCCESS' even when I get address not found in gmail

Comment: `mail.send` only puts the mail into the local mail handler, which will eventually process it and try to contact the recipient's domain's mail handler and attempt to deliver the message to it. It's basically just throwing the letter into the postbox, there's no guarantee it'll be delivered after this, and you can't get an immediate answer to that. There would have to be something wrong with handing the mail to the local mail handler for this to throw an exception.

Comment: @deceze In short, there is no way of knowing if a user provides an email that does not exist. I wanted to be able to achieve this to return to a user a message that the email they have provided does not exist

Comment: It's not *impossible* per se, it's just not realistic most of the time. You could try to contact the target mail server via SMTP and either attempt to deliver the message directly, or at least go through the delivery protocol up to the point where the target server would indicate that the recipient address doesn't exist. This would have to happen within your Flask handler and the HTTP request would have to wait until that's done. The problem is that this may take a while, and that there may be network problems and the recipient server isn't available right now. [...]

Comment: Mail is decentralised and based on a store-and-retry architecture for a reason. Further the recipient server may refuse to talk to your web server directly due to spam concerns, which is the reason mail is often delivered through bigger, trusted mail servers first which will attempt the actual delivery. So… many reasons this isn't realistic.

Comment: And even if it were realistic, you could only check that the email existed. You would still need to check that it belonged to the person who just filled it out, and the only way to do that is to send them an email and have them click a link. There's a reason nearly all login systems work this way.

Comment: @Thomas. I think that I will go with your advice. The best is to ask them to provide an email where we can send then a link which they would follow to proceed.